# Weird Null pointer

Tags: java, pointers, null, nullpointerexception

I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Display.readFile(Display.java:55)
    at Display.<init>(Display.java:36)
    at Expordium.play(Expordium.java:15)
    at Expordium.main(Expordium.java:8)
```

This is one class of my code:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument.Iterator;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class Display extends JPanel implements Runnable{

private JFrame f = new JFrame("Expordium");
private Collection<Block> elements = new ArrayList<Block>();

private Wall wall;

private String file;
private Expordium game;
private String[][] strLevel;



public void start(Expordium g){
    strLevel = new String[30][10];
    game=g;
    f.getContentPane().add(new Display());
    f.setSize(960 , 320);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
Display(){
    readFile();
    for(int i=0; i<30; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<30; j++){
            if(strLevel[i][j].equals("*")){
                elements.add(wall=new Wall(i*16,j*16,true,"C:/Program Files (x86)/Software/eclipse/Programs/Expordium/Picture/Block/Grass-T.PNG"));
            }
        }
    }
}

public void run() {
    repaint();
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    java.util.Iterator<Block> iterator = elements.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext())
        ((Block) iterator.next()).draw(g);

}

private void readFile() {
    int num=0;
    String loc ="C:/Program Files (x86)/Software/eclipse/Programs/Expordium/Level/Level ";
    loc.concat(game.getLevel());
    loc.concat(".txt");
    File Level = new File(loc);
    file=TextFile.getContents(Level);
    for(int i=0; i<30; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<30; j++){
            strLevel[i][j]=file.substring(num, num+1);
            num++;
        }
    }
}

}
```

Also I get it on lines

loc.concat(".txt");

strLevel[i][j]=file.substring(num, num+1);

EDIT!!!!!!!
I changed the code to

```
    private void readFile() {
    int num=0;
    String loc ="C:/Program Files (x86)/Software/eclipse/Programs/Expordium/Level/Level 1.txt";
    File Level = new File(loc);
    file=TextFile.getContents(Level);
    for(int i=0; i<30; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<30; j++){
            System.out.println(file);
            strLevel[i][j]=file.substring(num, num+1);
            num++;
        }
    }
}
```

Now i get

---

- *
- *
- *
- *
- *
- *
- *
  *s                          e*

  ---

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Display.readFile(Display.java:66)
    at Display.(Display.java:36)
    at Expordium.play(Expordium.java:15)
    at Expordium.main(Expordium.java:8)

Comment: It would be nice to know which lines of the snippet correspond to your lines 55, 56 and 61, what is `TextFile`, how `getContents` is defined, ...

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code? Put a breakpoint on line 55 (which ever that one is), and have a look at the variable values.

Comment: Where are you initializing `strLevel`? Where do you declare `file`?

Comment: printed all the Strings and values and i get what its suppose to be

Comment: Strings are immutable in java, so `loc.concat(game.getLevel())` is doing absolutely nothing (try `loc = loc.concat(...)`), and therefore your `new File(loc)` is probably failing, which at some point will cause a null to pop up and make the code throw a NPE.

Comment: I changed it to loc = loc.concat(game.getLevel()); and I still get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:
game is null when you try to call game.getLevel().

Longer answer:
In Display's constructor, the first thing you do (before doing anything with game which will be null) is call readFile(). In readFile(), you invoke game.getLevel() prior to setting game equal to anything. It appears that you want start to set the game instance, but it hasn't been called prior to trying to use it, so that's the source of your NPE.

Comment: Ok... so if i got ride completely the game.getLevel(); what is it then if i get it on strLevel[i][j]=file.substring(num, num+1);... i edited my post

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code in a debugger to see what the values of the relevant variables are? It's possible that file is null, too, depending on what the functionality of TextFile.getContents(File f) is. If you don't have a debugger, download Eclipse. It's free and fairly easy to use.